# AngularJS 1 Delay route until model is loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, routes, angularjs-routing

I have just started learning AngularJS and am building a website to develop my skills.

I'm trying to **delay angular from routing to a new page until the JSON data is loaded**.

I cant find an answer on stack overflow that uses an angular factory to load the JSON.

My files are as follows.

services.js

```
app.factory('contactFormData', ['$http', function($http, $q) {
    return $http.get('json/eager-contactform.json')
    .success(function(data) {
        return data;
    })
    .error(function(err) {
        return err;
    })
}])
```

ContactController.js

```
app.controller('ContactController', ['$scope', 'contactFormData', '$http', function($scope, contactFormData, $http) {
    contactFormData.success(function(data) {
        $scope.contactFormData = data;
    })

    $scope.success = false;
    $scope.error = false;

    $scope.sendMessage = function(value) {
      $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'php/eagerContact.php',
          data: value,
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
      })
      .success( function(data) {
        if ( data.success ) {
          $scope.success = true;
        } else {
          $scope.error = true;
        }
      });
    }
}]);
```

app.js

```
var app = angular
    .module("eager", ['ngSanitize', 'ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) { 
      $routeProvider 
        .when('/contact', { 
          controller: 'ContactController', 
          templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
        }) 
        .otherwise({ 
          redirectTo: '/' 
        }); 
    });
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `resolve` option of route to wait to view to load before data gets loaded. For the same create a method in factory & exposed it to consumer of service via returning object.

**Factory**

```
app.factory('contactFormData', ['$http', function($http, $q) {
   var getEagerContactForm = function() {
     return $http.get('json/eager-contactform.json');
   }
   return {
     getEagerContactForm: getEagerContactForm 
   }
}])
```

**Config**

```
$routeProvider
.when('/contact', { 
  controller: 'ContactController', 
  templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
  resolve: {
     data: function(contactFormData){
        return contactFormData.getEagerContactForm();
     }
  }
})
```

Inside `ContactController` you could inject `data` as a dependency, which will have the data returned from API.